# Xcode - Building a framework is failing because of "mkdir: command not found"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I'm really stuck on this one. I am attempting to build a `iOS framework` (or static library) generally following the steps outlined [here](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework).

However, my framework library fails to build because of `mkdir: command not found`, which seems terribly odd to me because `mkdir` is pretty widely accessible I thought.

The build script that is generated is as follows (it's long; my apologies):

```
PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build/Script-8B31024B1878A743004417FE.sh
    cd /path/to/MyFramework
    setenv ACTION build
    setenv AD_HOC_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED NO
    setenv ALTERNATE_GROUP staff
    setenv ALTERNATE_MODE u+w,go-w,a+rX
    setenv ALTERNATE_OWNER MyUser
    setenv ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS NO
    setenv ALWAYS_USE_SEPARATE_HEADERMAPS YES
    setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_DEVELOPER_DIR /AppleInternal/Developer
    setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_DIR /AppleInternal
    setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_DOCUMENTATION_DIR /AppleInternal/Documentation
    setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_DIR /AppleInternal/Library
    setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_TOOLS /AppleInternal/Developer/Tools
    setenv APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_FILES NO
    setenv ARCHS armv7s
    setenv ARCHS_STANDARD "armv7 armv7s"
    setenv ARCHS_STANDARD_32_64_BIT "armv7 armv7s"
    setenv ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT "armv7 armv7s"
    setenv ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT arm64
    setenv ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT "armv7 armv7s arm64"
    setenv ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS "armv7 armv7s"
    setenv AVAILABLE_PLATFORMS "iphonesimulator macosx iphoneos"
    setenv BUILD_COMPONENTS "headers build"
    setenv BUILD_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Products
    setenv BUILD_ROOT /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Products
    setenv BUILD_STYLE 
    setenv BUILD_VARIANTS normal
    setenv BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
    setenv CACHE_ROOT /var/folders/0c/k84qhs2168336jg42_6nnph40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode
    setenv CCHROOT /var/folders/0c/k84qhs2168336jg42_6nnph40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode
    setenv CHMOD /bin/chmod
    setenv CHOWN /usr/sbin/chown
    setenv CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD c++0x
    setenv CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY libc++
    setenv CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES NO
    setenv CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC YES
    setenv CLANG_WARN_BOOL_CONVERSION YES
    setenv CLANG_WARN_CONSTANT_CONVERSION YES
    setenv CLANG_WARN_DIRECT_OBJC_ISA_USAGE YES_ERROR
    setenv CLANG_WARN_EMPTY_BODY YES
    setenv CLANG_WARN_ENUM_CONVERSION YES
    setenv CLANG_WARN_INT_CONVERSION YES
    setenv CLANG_WARN_OBJC_ROOT_CLASS YES_ERROR
    setenv CLANG_WARN__DUPLICATE_METHOD_MATCH YES
    setenv CLASS_FILE_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build/JavaClasses
    setenv CLEAN_PRECOMPS YES
    setenv CLONE_HEADERS NO
    setenv CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libMyFramework.a
    setenv CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED NO
    setenv CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED YES
    setenv CODE_SIGN_CONTEXT_CLASS XCiPhoneOSCodeSignContext
    setenv COLOR_DIAGNOSTICS NO
    setenv COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES NO
    setenv COMMAND_MODE legacy
    setenv COMPOSITE_SDK_DIRS /var/folders/0c/k84qhs2168336jg42_6nnph40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0.2-5A3005/Xcode/CompositeSDKs
    setenv COMPRESS_PNG_FILES YES
    setenv CONFIGURATION Debug
    setenv CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
    setenv CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos
    setenv COPYING_PRESERVES_HFS_DATA NO
    setenv COPY_PHASE_STRIP NO
    setenv COPY_RESOURCES_FROM_STATIC_FRAMEWORKS YES
    setenv CP /bin/cp
    setenv CREATE_INFOPLIST_SECTION_IN_BINARY NO
    setenv CURRENT_ARCH armv7s
    setenv CURRENT_VARIANT normal
    setenv DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING NO
    setenv DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS YES
    setenv DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT dwarf-with-dsym
    setenv DEFAULT_COMPILER com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
    setenv DEFAULT_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH /System/Library/Extensions
    setenv DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION NO
    setenv DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING NO
    setenv DERIVED_FILES_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build/DerivedSources
    setenv DERIVED_FILE_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build/DerivedSources
    setenv DERIVED_SOURCES_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build/DerivedSources
    setenv DEVELOPER_APPLICATIONS_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications
    setenv DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
    setenv DEVELOPER_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    setenv DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks
    setenv DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR_QUOTED /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks
    setenv DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library
    setenv DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
    setenv DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
    setenv DEVELOPER_USR_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
    setenv DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE English
    setenv DO_HEADER_SCANNING_IN_JAM NO
    setenv DSTROOT /tmp/MyFramework.dst
    setenv DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
    setenv DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME libMyFramework.a.dSYM
    setenv DWARF_DSYM_FILE_SHOULD_ACCOMPANY_PRODUCT NO
    setenv DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
    setenv EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME -iphoneos
    setenv EMBEDDED_PROFILE_NAME embedded.mobileprovision
    setenv ENABLE_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES YES
    setenv ENTITLEMENTS_REQUIRED YES
    setenv EXCLUDED_INSTALLSRC_SUBDIRECTORY_PATTERNS ".DS_Store .svn .git .hg CVS"
    setenv EXCLUDED_RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATH_SUBDIRECTORIES "*.nib *.lproj *.framework *.gch (*) .DS_Store CVS .svn .git .hg *.xcodeproj *.xcode *.pbproj *.pbxproj"
    setenv EXECUTABLE_EXTENSION a
    setenv EXECUTABLE_NAME libMyFramework.a
    setenv EXECUTABLE_PATH libMyFramework.a
    setenv EXECUTABLE_PREFIX lib
    setenv EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX .a
    setenv FILE_LIST /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build/Objects/LinkFileList
    setenv FIXED_FILES_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build/FixedFiles
    setenv FRAMEWORK_FLAG_PREFIX -framework
    setenv FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS "/path/to/MyFramework/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos  /path/to/MyFramework/MyFramework/lib"
    setenv FRAMEWORK_VERSION A
    setenv FULL_PRODUCT_NAME libMyFramework.a
    setenv GCC3_VERSION 3.3
    setenv GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD compiler-default
    setenv GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC NO
    setenv GCC_ENABLE_SYMBOL_SEPARATION NO
    setenv GCC_INLINES_ARE_PRIVATE_EXTERN YES
    setenv GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL 0
    setenv GCC_PFE_FILE_C_DIALECTS "c objective-c c++ objective-c++"
    setenv GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER YES
    setenv GCC_PREFIX_HEADER MyFramework/MyFramework-Prefix.pch
    setenv GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS "DEBUG=1 "
    setenv GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN NO
    setenv GCC_THUMB_SUPPORT YES
    setenv GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS NO
    setenv GCC_VERSION com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
    setenv GCC_VERSION_IDENTIFIER com_apple_compilers_llvm_clang_1_0
    setenv GCC_WARN_64_TO_32_BIT_CONVERSION YES
    setenv GCC_WARN_ABOUT_RETURN_TYPE YES_ERROR
    setenv GCC_WARN_UNDECLARED_SELECTOR YES
    setenv GCC_WARN_UNINITIALIZED_AUTOS YES
    setenv GCC_WARN_UNUSED_FUNCTION YES
    setenv GCC_WARN_UNUSED_VARIABLE YES
    setenv GENERATE_MASTER_OBJECT_FILE NO
    setenv GENERATE_PKGINFO_FILE NO
    setenv GENERATE_PROFILING_CODE NO
    setenv GID 20
    setenv GROUP staff
    setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_FLAT_ENTRIES_FOR_TARGET_BEING_BUILT YES
    setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_FRAMEWORK_ENTRIES_FOR_ALL_PRODUCT_TYPES YES
    setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_NONPUBLIC_NONPRIVATE_HEADERS YES
    setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_PROJECT_HEADERS YES
    setenv HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS "/path/to/MyFramework/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include  /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include /path/to/MyFramework/MyFramework/lib/opencv2.framework/Headers /path/to/MyFramework/MyFramework/lib/opencv2.framework/Headers"
    setenv ICONV /usr/bin/iconv
    setenv INFOPLIST_EXPAND_BUILD_SETTINGS YES
    setenv INFOPLIST_OUTPUT_FORMAT binary
    setenv INFOPLIST_PREPROCESS NO
    setenv INSTALL_DIR /tmp/MyFramework.dst/usr/local/lib
    setenv INSTALL_GROUP staff
    setenv INSTALL_MODE_FLAG u+w,go-w,a+rX
    setenv INSTALL_OWNER MyUser
    setenv INSTALL_PATH /usr/local/lib
    setenv INSTALL_ROOT /tmp/MyFramework.dst
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 7.0
    setenv JAVAC_DEFAULT_FLAGS "-J-Xms64m -J-XX:NewSize=4M -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"
    setenv JAVA_APP_STUB /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Resources/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
    setenv JAVA_ARCHIVE_CLASSES YES
    setenv JAVA_ARCHIVE_TYPE JAR
    setenv JAVA_COMPILER /usr/bin/javac
    setenv JAVA_FRAMEWORK_RESOURCES_DIRS Resources
    setenv JAVA_JAR_FLAGS cv
    setenv JAVA_SOURCE_SUBDIR .
    setenv JAVA_USE_DEPENDENCIES YES
    setenv JAVA_ZIP_FLAGS -urg
    setenv JIKES_DEFAULT_FLAGS "+E +OLDCSO"
    setenv KEEP_PRIVATE_EXTERNS NO
    setenv LD_DEPENDENCY_INFO_FILE /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/MyFramework_dependency_info.dat
    setenv LD_GENERATE_MAP_FILE NO
    setenv LD_MAP_FILE_PATH /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build/MyFramework-LinkMap-normal-armv7s.txt
    setenv LD_NO_PIE NO
    setenv LD_QUOTE_LINKER_ARGUMENTS_FOR_COMPILER_DRIVER YES
    setenv LEGACY_DEVELOPER_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer
    setenv LEX lex
    setenv LIBRARY_FLAG_NOSPACE YES
    setenv LIBRARY_FLAG_PREFIX -l
    setenv LIBRARY_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH /Library/Extensions
    setenv LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS "/path/to/MyFramework/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos "
    setenv LINKER_DISPLAYS_MANGLED_NAMES NO
    setenv LINK_FILE_LIST_normal_armv7s /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/MyFramework.LinkFileList
    setenv LINK_WITH_STANDARD_LIBRARIES YES
    setenv LOCAL_ADMIN_APPS_DIR /Applications/Utilities
    setenv LOCAL_APPS_DIR /Applications
    setenv LOCAL_DEVELOPER_DIR /Library/Developer
    setenv LOCAL_LIBRARY_DIR /Library
    setenv MACH_O_TYPE staticlib
    setenv MAC_OS_X_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION 13B42
    setenv MAC_OS_X_VERSION_ACTUAL 1091
    setenv MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAJOR 1090
    setenv MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MINOR 0901
    setenv MODULE_CACHE_DIR /Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache
    setenv NATIVE_ARCH armv7
    setenv NATIVE_ARCH_32_BIT i386
    setenv NATIVE_ARCH_64_BIT x86_64
    setenv NATIVE_ARCH_ACTUAL x86_64
    setenv NO_COMMON YES
    setenv OBJECT_FILE_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build/Objects
    setenv OBJECT_FILE_DIR_normal /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build/Objects-normal
    setenv OBJROOT /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates
    setenv ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH YES
    setenv OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL 0
    setenv OS MACOS
    setenv OSAC /usr/bin/osacompile
    setenv OTHER_CFLAGS -mfpu=neon
    setenv OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS -mfpu=neon
    setenv OTHER_LDFLAGS -ObjC
    setenv PACKAGE_TYPE com.apple.package-type.static-library
    setenv PASCAL_STRINGS YES
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/libexec:/Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools:/Users/MyUser/GenePeeks/SourceCode/bedtools2-2.19.0/bin"
    setenv PATH_PREFIXES_EXCLUDED_FROM_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES "/usr/include /usr/local/include /System/Library/Frameworks /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Headers /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/SDKs /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms"
    setenv PFE_FILE_C_DIALECTS "objective-c c++ objective-c++"
    setenv PKGINFO_FILE_PATH /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build/PkgInfo
    setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_APPLICATIONS_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Applications
    setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin
    setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library
    setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs
    setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Tools
    setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr
    setenv PLATFORM_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
    setenv PLATFORM_NAME iphoneos
    setenv PLATFORM_PREFERRED_ARCH arm64
    setenv PLATFORM_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION 11B508
    setenv PLIST_FILE_OUTPUT_FORMAT binary
    setenv PRECOMPS_INCLUDE_HEADERS_FROM_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR YES
    setenv PRECOMP_DESTINATION_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build/PrefixHeaders
    setenv PRESERVE_DEAD_CODE_INITS_AND_TERMS NO
    setenv PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH /usr/local/include
    setenv PRODUCT_NAME MyFramework
    setenv PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH 
    setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.library.static
    setenv PROFILING_CODE NO
    setenv PROJECT MyFramework
    setenv PROJECT_DERIVED_FILE_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/DerivedSources
    setenv PROJECT_DIR /path/to/MyFramework
    setenv PROJECT_FILE_PATH /path/to/MyFramework/MyFramework.xcodeproj
    setenv PROJECT_NAME MyFramework
    setenv PROJECT_TEMP_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build
    setenv PROJECT_TEMP_ROOT /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates
    setenv PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH Headers
    setenv RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATHS_FOLLOW_SYMLINKS YES
    setenv REMOVE_CVS_FROM_RESOURCES YES
    setenv REMOVE_GIT_FROM_RESOURCES YES
    setenv REMOVE_HG_FROM_RESOURCES YES
    setenv REMOVE_SVN_FROM_RESOURCES YES
    setenv REZ_COLLECTOR_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build/ResourceManagerResources
    setenv REZ_EXECUTABLE YES
    setenv REZ_OBJECTS_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build/ResourceManagerResources/Objects
    setenv REZ_SEARCH_PATHS "/path/to/MyFramework/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos "
    setenv SCAN_ALL_SOURCE_FILES_FOR_INCLUDES NO
    setenv SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_COUNT 0
    setenv SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_COUNT 0
    setenv SDKROOT /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk
    setenv SDK_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk
    setenv SDK_NAME iphoneos7.0
    setenv SDK_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION 11B508
    setenv SED /usr/bin/sed
    setenv SEPARATE_STRIP YES
    setenv SEPARATE_SYMBOL_EDIT NO
    setenv SET_DIR_MODE_OWNER_GROUP YES
    setenv SET_FILE_MODE_OWNER_GROUP NO
    setenv SHARED_DERIVED_FILE_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/DerivedSources
    setenv SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders
    setenv SKIP_INSTALL YES
    setenv SOURCE_ROOT /path/to/MyFramework
    setenv SRCROOT /path/to/MyFramework
    setenv STRINGS_FILE_OUTPUT_ENCODING binary
    setenv STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT YES
    setenv STRIP_STYLE non-global
    setenv SUPPORTED_DEVICE_FAMILIES 1,2
    setenv SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS "iphonesimulator iphoneos"
    setenv SYMROOT /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Products
    setenv SYSTEM_ADMIN_APPS_DIR /Applications/Utilities
    setenv SYSTEM_APPS_DIR /Applications
    setenv SYSTEM_CORE_SERVICES_DIR /System/Library/CoreServices
    setenv SYSTEM_DEMOS_DIR /Applications/Extras
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_APPS_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DEMOS_DIR "/Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Built Examples"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DOC_DIR "/Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_GRAPHICS_TOOLS_DIR "/Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Graphics Tools"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_JAVA_TOOLS_DIR "/Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Java Tools"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_PERFORMANCE_TOOLS_DIR "/Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Performance Tools"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_RELEASENOTES_DIR "/Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library/releasenotes"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DOC_DIR "/Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library/documentation/DeveloperTools"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_RELEASENOTES_DIR "/Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library/releasenotes/DeveloperTools"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_UTILITIES_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Utilities
    setenv SYSTEM_DOCUMENTATION_DIR /Library/Documentation
    setenv SYSTEM_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH /System/Library/Extensions
    setenv SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR /System/Library
    setenv TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY 1
    setenv TARGETNAME MyFramework
    setenv TARGET_BUILD_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
    setenv TARGET_NAME MyFramework
    setenv TARGET_TEMP_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build
    setenv TEMP_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build
    setenv TEMP_FILES_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build
    setenv TEMP_FILE_DIR /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build
    setenv TEMP_ROOT /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates
    setenv TOOLCHAINS com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault
    setenv UID 501
    setenv UNSTRIPPED_PRODUCT NO
    setenv USER MyUser
    setenv USER_APPS_DIR /Users/MyUser/Applications
    setenv USER_LIBRARY_DIR /Users/MyUser/Library
    setenv USE_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC YES
    setenv USE_HEADERMAP YES
    setenv USE_HEADER_SYMLINKS NO
    setenv VALIDATE_PRODUCT NO
    setenv VALID_ARCHS "arm64 armv7 armv7s"
    setenv VERBOSE_PBXCP NO
    setenv VERSION_INFO_BUILDER MyUser
    setenv VERSION_INFO_FILE MyFramework_vers.c
    setenv VERSION_INFO_STRING "\"@(#)PROGRAM:MyFramework  PROJECT:MyFramework-\""
    setenv XCODE_APP_SUPPORT_DIR /Applications/Xcode/5.0/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode
    setenv XCODE_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION 5A3005
    setenv XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL 0502
    setenv XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR 0500
    setenv XCODE_VERSION_MINOR 0500
    setenv XPCSERVICES_FOLDER_PATH /XPCServices
    setenv YACC yacc
    setenv arch armv7s
    setenv variant normal
    /bin/sh -c /path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build/Script-8B31024B1878A743004417FE.sh
```

at which point it **fails** and reports the error as:

```
/path/to/MyFramework/Build/Intermediates/MyFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.build/Script-8B31024B1878A743004417FE.sh: line 5: mkdir: command not found
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 127
```

The script `Script-8B31024B1878A743004417FE.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

mkdir -p "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/Headers"

# Link the "Current" version to "A"
/bin/ln -sfh A "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/Current"
/bin/ln -sfh Versions/Current/Headers "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Headers"
/bin/ln -sfh "Versions/Current/${PRODUCT_NAME}" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/${PRODUCT_NAME}"

# The -a ensures that the headers maintain the source modification date so that we don't constantly
# cause propagating rebuilds of files that import these headers.
/bin/cp -a "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH}/" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/Headers"
```

Does anyone have any experience with building `MyFramework.framework` type libraries using this method? **Any idea where I could be going wrong???**

Comment: My 2 cents when I went through this tutorial and through issues I have had, Delete the .m file and make sure you have added some other files like Widget.h/.m and then build and made the .h public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use /bin/mkdir as thats where it is ... i dont know your $PATH contains so thats my 'easy fix'

Comment: Wow, that did it. I guess my `$PATH` lost a reference to `/bin/` perhaps. Thanks!!!

Comment: The PATH passed to the script is shown in that list of environment variables. It contains the usual Xcode tool paths, and `/Users/MyUser/GenePeeks/SourceCode/bedtools2-2.19.0/bin`, but none of the standard Unix paths like /bin and /usr/bin.